# Python CX Oracle Wildcard Like Query

Tags: python, oracle

hi i am trying to use wildcard query:

```
c.execute( """ select seq_id from schema.table1 where table_id = :table_id and context_2 like :recipe_name || '%' """, {"table_id" : table_id, "recipe_name" : recipe_name} ) 

result:
res = []
```

when i changed to

```
c.execute( """ select seq_id from schema.table1 where table_id = :table_id and context_2 like \'%abc%\' """, {"table_id" : table_id} )

result:
res = {list}[(166,),(167)]
```

what might be wrong in my code? i use same logic :var_name || '%'

Comment: hi i have editted my code